# SharePoint page under Pages library not loading

Tags: sharepoint-online

When clicking on a link to a SharePoint page(newpage.aspx) from another page, it is taking to the actual page library rather than the page itself. When I switch to classic experience it loads the page.

Can someone please tell why it is happening?

Comment: is this link on the navigation or in the page itself ?

Comment: The link is on the default page of a Subsite.

Answer (score 1):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I can access one page from another page by the link, it can load the page.

Did you switch to classic experience in the Pages library?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if the URL of the page(newpage.aspx) is right.
2. Create a new page library and check if the same issue will occur.

If the issue only occurs in the Pages library, you could create a new page library and move the content to the new page library.